# Always run a given program as an administrator in Windows 8.1 without prompt

Tags: windows-8, administrator, uac, windows-8.1

I have set up a program to always run as an administrator using the Compatability setting in Properties, which is necessary as the program always require administrator rights. Is there a way to make so that the User Account Control prompt does not always pop up and require me to confirm that I want to run this as an administrator? I am on an administrator account. I know I can simply turn off all User Account Control notifications, but I would rather not do this for security purposes; rather, I just want UAC settings to remember the choice I made regarding running the program as an administrator but not prompt me to confirm it.

[This](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html) is an example of what I want, but that was made for Windows 7 and I'm not sure how well it work in 8.1.

Comment: What you want requires a prompt

Comment: -1 re your last line, you're not sure how well it will work in windows 8.1? try it

Comment: even when given an answer of what to try, you don't know whether it will work unless you try it. that guide you link to has lots of pictures and you haven't struggled with any of it 'cos you haven't tried it. you haven't found it daunting you just haven't tried it.  You could've tried it in the time it took to write your question. And if you tried it and it hadn't worked then you could've written a far better more well informed question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Task Scheduler [trick you mention](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html) still works fine in Windows 8.x. I use it daily. You can use it without any issues.

Comment: +1 to cancel the idiot that downvoted you without comment.

Answer (score 1):

Open Windows PowerShell (open it as an Administrator) and Run below registry settings:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "EnableLUA" -Value "0"
```

Comment: -1 because he said he doesn't want to disable the UAC.

Answer (score 1):

[Click here for a few options:](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-eliminate-uac-prompts-for-specific-applications-493128966)

The first involves creating a link to a task you will create using task manager for the application.  The task is set to launch immediately and with elevated privileges and the other solutions rely on 3rd party software.

Search Words: uac suppress prompt

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft's Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit(ADK)'s Compatibility Administrator.  You can find a good starting tutorial [here](http://meridian.ws/wordpress/?p=306).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found was to go to the EXE file, right-click and select Troubleshoot compatibility. There you'll have an option to select that the program requires additional permissions at which point the program will be changed to run as administrator. Save the changes and you're all set.

Comment: this triggers the UAC prompt again which he wants to avoid ;)